# Static volatile field has different values within class per two Spring application contexts in two liferay portlets

Tags: java, spring, liferay

This class is defined in project I. Project II and project III both have project I as a dependency.

```
public class A {

    private static volatile int schemaVersion = -1;

    public synchronized void incrementSchemaVersion() {
        value++;
    }

}
```

**Project II** and **project III** have Spring application contexts and they create liferay portlets.

I would expect that when a thread which works within project II application context and increments value of schemaVersion, that this value would be visible for any other thread working also in project III application context.

This is not the case.

I have code which increments the value of schema version from within project II. This change happens, I checked. Later, when project III comes in and tries to check the schemaVersion value, it is still -1.

Does spring do something strange with static values? Should not a static value be one per JVM?

Comment: Could you please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  so that it is easier to test your classes?

Comment: Can you also put something in that checks the classloader for `A` from the three different projects, and see whether the same classloader is being used?

Comment: @LukeMelaia Unfortunately isolating only parts that would be required would take a lot of time and I would have to provide files, otherwise you would have to write them on your own based on what I would post - that would take also long time for anyone to try. This is why I only resort to explanation. You need three projects with dependency as mentioned. Both have separate application contexts referring to the same one from project I. The II and III are liferay portlets projects. Deploy II and III on a clean liferay instance and you are all set. You can imagine doing this would take a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the only way this could happen is if class `A` were loaded separately, using different classloaders, for each project. In that case, you'd end up with three different copies of `A`, and each would have its own `static` field called `schemaVersion`.

Changes to one would then not be reflected in the other.

You'd need to check this by putting something in to see whether the classloader is the same for the three projects. You can get to the classloader with something like

```
ClassLoader loader = A.class.getClassLoader();
```

Do that from the three projects and see if you end up with the same `loader`.

Be aware that `getClassLoader()` can return `null`, in which case it means the class was loaded by the bootstrap classloader.

Comment: Could you help me find out, how to check if the same classloader is being used or not?

Comment: @Ev0oD I've added something about this.

Comment: Seems like there is no need to try even. Here https://www.liferay.com/web/pmesotten/blog/-/blogs/classloading-in-liferay they say that each portlet is on a different classpath - loaded separately. I think this explains it - The class and the whole library is probably duplicated and present in each portlet hook. Thus the problem.

Comment: Each _portlet plugin_ has its own class loader - as it is a separate webapp. But you can have more than one portlet in one plugin - which would use the same class loader then.

Comment: Ah, okay. I presume I cannot deploy two war projects into (or as) one portlet plugin though.